# изменение ссылки href при помощи jQuery в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет! Делаю таблицу с товаром, в которой будет меняться количество товара и сумма заказа. На кнопку "купить" меняется ссылка подобным образом: берется значение из data-id (здесь будет id товара) и подставляется количество из переменной count. Но так как у меня таблица, то ссылка меняется неправильно, т.е. не в той строке, в которой меняем количество. Как можно сделать так, чтобы ссылка менялась в нужной строке?? Помогите, пожалуйста. 
(P.s.) во второй строке тег input отображаю в type=text для удобства.

Разметка:

```
   <table align="center"style="width:70%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>наименование</th>
            <th>количество</th>
            <th>цена</th>
            <th>подробнее</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Товар первый</td>
            <td>
                <span class="minus">-</span>
                <input class="quantity" type="text" size="3" min="0" step="0" max="0" value="1" />
                <span class="plus">+</span>
                <input class="link" type="hidden" data-id="111" value="" style="width:100%;"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/site/?action=ADD2BASKET&id=0001" class="url_page">
                    <span class="count_price" data-price="200"> 200 </span><span> руб.</span>
                    Купить
                </a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/site/section/product-1/" class="url_page_detail">
                Подробнее</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Товар второй</td>
            <td>
                <span class="minus">-</span>
                <input class="quantity" type="text" size="3" min="0" step="0" max="0" value="1" />
                <span class="plus">+</span>
                <input class="link" type="text" data-id="111" value="" style="width:100%;"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/site/?action=ADD2BASKET&id=0002" class="url_page">
                    <span class="count_price" data-price="100"> 100 </span><span> руб.</span>
                    Купить
                </a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/site/section/product-2/" class="url_page_detail">
                Подробнее</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Код jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        function change($tr, val) {
            var $input = $tr.find('.quantity');
            var count = parseInt($input.val()) + val;
            count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
            $input.val(count);
            var $price = $tr.find('.count_price');
            $price.text(count * $price.data('price'));

            var add_url = $('a.url_page_detail').attr('href'); // берем ссылку из атриб. href class="url_page";
            var $input = $tr.find('.link'); // находим строку, где будут изменения;
            $input.val(add_url + '?action=ADD2BASKET&id=' + $input.data('id') + '&QUANTITY=' + count); // записывает значение в эту строку;

            var $href = $tr.find('.url_page'); // нахоим нужную строку и меняем ссылку;
                $href.attr('href', $('.link').val());
            var BBB = $('.link').val();
            //  console.log(BBB);
        }
        $('.minus').click(function() {
            change($(this).closest('tr'), -1);
        });
        $('.plus').click(function() {
            change($(this).closest('tr'), 1);
        });
        $('.quantity').on("input", function() {
            var $price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.count_price');
            $price.text(this.value * $price.data('price'));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Вот вы во всех местах поставили $tr.find, а в одном забыли...

Comment: @PavelMayorov потому что во всех местах не его код, а там где забыл - его код...

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko возможно, но какая разница?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну да, совершенно верно. Это мне помогли написать вы, за что я вам благодарен. Но вот разбираясь дальше, опять зашёл в тупик. Изучение занимаюсь, а вот потребности в таком функционале есть, к сожалению...

Comment: `add_url` - вот здесь, ищите через `$tr.find`, как например мы `.quantity` ищем.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko но ведь через `add_url` я беру только ссылку на страницу, а остальное подставляю уже в другой элемент. Т.е. у меня в итоге подставляет везде полученный первый результат `input class="link" value=()` ... Хотя тут я тоже с вами согласен, что значение в `add_url` нужно брать с нужной строки

Comment: У вас селектор  `a.url_page_detail` берет все элементы с классом `.url_page_detail`, а не в той строке, в которой меняете количество.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko тут я с вами согласен. Уже исправляю эту ошибку. Но проблема заключается в другом. У меня полученное значение `input class="link" value=()` дальше должно изменять атрибут href у ссылки с классом `class="url_page"`, а в итоге во второй строке берётся значение первой строки... Как быть здесь?...

Comment: вот эти исправления, сейчас в значение записывает верную информацию `var $add_url = $tr.find('.url_page_detail').attr('href');
   var $input = $tr.find('.link');`
Теперь вот это значение нужно в элемент `<a href=# class="url_page">` как-то загрузить... Не получается загрузить из нужной строки, выгружается из первой

Answer (score 0):

Всё, нашёл свои ошибки. Оказывается просто было) Надо было фильтр применить еще раз

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function change($tr, val) {
        var $input = $tr.find('.quantity');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) + val;
        count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        var $price = $tr.find('.count_price');
        $price.text(count * $price.data('price'));


        var $add_url = $tr.find('.url_page_detail').attr('href'); 
        var $input = $tr.find('.link'); 
        $input.val($add_url + '?action=ADD2BASKET&id=' + $input.data('id') + '&QUANTITY=' + count); // строим ссылку;

        var $href = $tr.find('.url_page'); 
        var $href_res = $tr.find('.link').val(); 
            $href.attr('href', $href_res);
    }
    $('.minus').click(function() {
        change($(this).closest('tr'), -1);
    });
    $('.plus').click(function() {
        change($(this).closest('tr'), 1);
    }); 
    $('.quantity').on("input", function() {
        var $price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.count_price');
        $price.text(this.value * $price.data('price'));
    });
});
```